# How to compute $m_i^\mathsf{T}(A-B_i)^{-1}m_i$, with $A$ and $B_i$ p.s.d, efficiently?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A$ and matrices $B_i=L_i^\mathsf{T} M_i L_i$. I want to estimate  the following quantity for $i\in [1,n]$,
\begin{eqnarray}
m_i^\mathsf{T}(A-B_i)^{-1}m_i
\end{eqnarray}
$A$ and $B_i$ are all positive semidefinite.

How to use this structure to compute the above values efficiently?

What I have thought is the following

1-Simply solve the linear system $(A-B_i)x = m_i$, using lapack.

2-Use some iterative method, that uses the following iteration
\begin{eqnarray}
x^{(k+1)} = A^{-1} m_i + A^{-1} B_i x^{(k)}
\end{eqnarray}

which one is faster, overall? Is there any iterative method, proper for this problem? I have the factorization $B_i=L_i^\mathsf{T} M_i L_i$, is there any way to use this information to speed up computation even more?

Comment: Is there a relation between $m_i$ and $M_i$?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Do $L_i$ or $M_i$ have some structure? How large is $n$ comparing to the size of the matrices? Notice that $A-B_i$ or $A$ need not to be invertible or well-condition.

Comment: Both $A$ and $B_i$ are invertible but $A-B_i$ can be ill-condition.

Comment: only from condition perspective, I would prefer method 2 over 1. Method 2 is also good if $A$ has structure and $L_i$ and $M_i$ are sparse.

Comment: If $A$ is a multiple of the identity and $L_i$ is orthogonal, you have $A-B_i = L_i^T (A-M_i) L_i$... but otherwise it is often work to update a factorization.

Comment: Unless there's something more you want to or can say about $A$ and $B_i$, I would certainly prefer to use method 1. Out of curiosity, what is the size of $A$?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel out of curiosity, why would you prefer method 1?

Comment: @user251257 method 1 gives *a* solution, method 2 cannot converge (it's not even a fixed point).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel $(A-B_i)x = m_i \iff x = A^{-1}m_i + A^{-1}B_i x$. So it is a fix-point. Well obviously one need to check $\|A^{-1} B_i\| < 1$.

Comment: @user251257 true my bad, method 1 gives a solution, method 2 gives maybe a solution. That's one less maybe for method 1.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel well. It depends. Method 1 fails if $A - B_i$ isn't invertible.In both case one need more details.

Comment: @user251257  indeed well if it's not invertible there's no "other" method which would make it invertible in the first place.

Comment: I tested both methods, Method 2 converged but method 1 is too much faster. I wanted to find a method faster than method 1, but unfortunately due to eigen values of $A^{-1}B_i$, which are near 1, convergence of the method, takes a longe time.